# All possible combinations of columns and rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, math, combinations

I have this Dataframe that I want to get all possible combinations of this dataframe across both rows and columns.

| A_Points | B_Points | C_Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 9 | 2 | 4 |

For example a combination as follows Points = 0 + 5 + 4, or 9 + 1 + 1.
Is there a builtin tool for such problem?

This is what I tried, but it did not give the desired output.

```
> import itertools
> combined_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'{}{}'.format(a, b): possible_feature_characteristicpoints[a] - possible_feature_characteristicpoints[b] for a, b in itertools.combinations(possible_feature_characteristicpoints.columns, 2)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
from itertools import product

out = list(map(sum, product(*df.to_numpy().tolist())))
```

Output:

```
[12, 5, 7, 14, 7, 9, 13, 6, 8, 13, 6, 8, 15, 8, 10, 14, 7, 9, 13, 6, 8, 15, 8, 10, 14, 7, 9]
```

Intermediate:

```
list(product(*df.to_numpy().tolist()))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3, 9),
 (0, 3, 2),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (0, 5, 9),
 (0, 5, 2),
 (0, 5, 4),
 ...
 (1, 4, 2),
 (1, 4, 4)]
```

Comment: Would this also work if it were more than three columns?

Comment: Yes, any number of columns would work. Just keep in mind that with many columns the number of combinations explodes!

Answer (score 0):

Another way with **list comprehension**,

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
  "A_Points": [0,3,9],
  "B_Points": [1,5,2],
  "C_Points": [1,4,4],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = [ (i, j, k)
    for i in df.A_Points
    for j in df.B_Points
    for k in df.C_Points
]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 4), (0, 1, 4), (0, 5, 1), (0, 5, 4), (0, 5, 4), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 4), (0, 2, 4), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 4), (3, 1, 4), (3, 5, 1), (3, 5, 4), (3, 5, 4), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 4), (3, 2, 4), (9, 1, 1), (9, 1, 4), (9, 1, 4), (9, 5, 1), (9, 5, 4), (9, 5, 4), (9, 2, 1), (9, 2, 4), (9, 2, 4)]
```